# CSWP to show results based on Subsites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, sub-site, cswp

Environment: SharePoint 2013
I have 05 Subsites 
Example:

'code'
- ABC
- XYZ
- Project1
- Finance
- Administration

'code'

Please suggest what should be the search criteria for CSWP to pull the names with the link to the respective SubSites.
I`ve checked on the internet and yes there are article but that is when you have subsites with common name e.g. Project1,2,3,4.

However, in my case all have different names and wondering what common element can be used?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Title managed property with the query ContentClass=STS_Web.

Comment: Matthew, it does show all sites part of site ABC, URL: https://intranet.example.com/projects/abc

Query Text:
path:"https://intranet.example.com/projects/abc"  ContentClass=STS_Web

So it shows all sites part of ABC main site, but even show the URL of ABC too. I dont want ABC site in the search result. 
So followed the article: https://jamesdiblasi.wordpress.com/2013/12/05/display-subsites-in-a-webpart/

Created new Query Text:
path:"https://intranet.example.com/projects/abc"  ContentClass=STS_Web site <>abc

But it doesnt works.
I guess bcoz my search Path contains abc, any idea?